# Hint for proving some meromorphic functions are rational

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to answer the following question

[image]

I should note that this is from Serge Lange's Introduction to Complex Analysis.

**My thoughts:** I was thinking that I could approach this by contradiction. However, I am not sure what would be the opposite. I understand that the opposite to a rational function is an irational but I am not sure how to write it mathematically. I was thinking of arguing something ofthe lines that if $f$ is not rational then

$$f(z)=\frac{\sum a_n z^n}{\sum b_n z^n}$$

with $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ each having infinetly many non zero terms (**I should note this above already looks wrong**). Next, I wanted to argue that the bottom fraction must be a multiple of the product of the singularities (including their order) by the fundamental theorem of algebra and what it means for a function to be meromprhic. However, I can't seem to find the next step. I haven't intigrated the condition that $\lim |f(z)| = \infty$ and I am not sure how to add it.

**My Question:** I feel like I am not looking at this correctly. Could someone let me know if I am going in the right direction (contradiction wise) and give me a **hint** towards the construction of the proof?

Comment: maybe you should use the fact that the both the zeroes and poles of a meromorphic function must be isolated. then use the fact that the 2-sphere is the one point compactification of the plane

Comment: A further hint: letting $g(z)=f(1/z)$, you know that $|g(z)|\to +\infty$ as $z\to 0$. If you already knew that that point was an isolated singularity, you'd know it was a pole of some order. Then argue that a non-isolated singularity cannot have that property...

Comment: Hi @user480840 thank you for the comment. I am afraid the book hasn’t covered Riemann spheres.

Comment: Hi @paulgarrett, thank you for the comment. I am struggling to understand what you mean as I would think your comment is in addition to the previous (to which I have responded I have not covered Riemann Spheres yet). Does one first start with assuming that it is not rational, and if yes, how does one write this mathematically?